# Utilizing BeautifulSoup on a completely flat HTML hierarchy

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

so I'm a webscraping noob, and ran into some HTML format i've never seen before. All the info I need is in a completely flat hierarchy. I need to grab the Date/MovieName/Location/Amenities.

It's laid out so (just like this):

```
<div class="caption">
  <strong>July 1</strong>
  <br>
  <em>Top Gun</em>
  <br>
  "Location: Millennium Park"
  <br>
  "Amenities: Please be a volleyball tournament..."
  <br>
  <em>Captain Phillips</em>
  <br>
  "Location: Montgomery Ward Park"
  <br>
  <br>
  <strong>July 2</strong>
  <br>
  <em>The Fantastic Mr. Fox </em>
```

I'd like to eventually have the format in a dictionary or a list to be able to write it out as a CSV file using csvwriter or Dictwriter; so an output like

[July 1, Top Gun, Millenium Park, "Please be a volleyball tournament..."],
[July 1, Captain Philips, Montgomery Ward Park, ] etc.

As you can see, annoyingly, when two movies are shown on the same date, the date is only displayed before the first movie; all the movies listed then until the next `<strong>somedate<strong>` fall under that initial date.

Suggestions guys? How do I make multiple movies fall under the date specified in the  tag above it? Possibly thinking find_next_siblings including checks whether the tag is a `<strong>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty ugly solution, and should be made more robust before you use it, but something like this should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv

doc = """<div class="caption">
  <strong>July 1</strong>
  <br>
  <em>Top Gun</em>
  <br>
  "Location: Millennium Park"
  <br>
  "Amenities: Please be a volleyball tournament..."
  <br>
  <em>Captain Phillips</em>
  <br>
  "Location: Montgomery Ward Park"
  <br>
  <br>
  <strong>July 2</strong>
  <br>
  <em>The Fantastic Mr. Fox </em>
  <br>
  "Location: Somewhere"
  <br>
  "Amenities: Something something"
  <br>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc.replace("<br>", "<br/>"))

data = []

for date in soup.find_all("strong"):
    sibling = date.next_sibling
    while sibling and sibling.name != "strong":
        if sibling.name == "em":
            title = sibling
            location = title.find_next("br").next
            extra = location.find_next("br").next

            row = []
            row.append(date.text)
            row.append(title.text)
            row.append(re.findall('(?<=:)[^"]*', location)[0])
            extra_val = re.findall('(?<=:)[^"]*', extra)
            if len(extra_val):
                row.append(extra_val[0])

            data.append(row)

        sibling = sibling.next_sibling

with open('foo.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Note the `doc.replace("<br>", "<br/>")` as BeautifulSoup otherwise interprets the `<br>` tags to wrap all the rest of the document.

To explain the `<br>` vs `<br/>` part further:

```
<p></p><em></em>
```

In the above HTML `em` is a sibling of `p`.

```
<p><em></em></p>
```

In this HTML `em` is a child of `p`. Now lets see how BeautifulSoup parses some HTML:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup('<br><p>Hello<br></p>', 'html.parser')
<br><p>Hello<br/></p></br>
>>> BeautifulSoup('<br><p>Hello<br></p>', 'html5lib')
<html><head></head><body><br/><p>Hello<br/></p></body></html>
```

`html.parser` is Pythons built-in HTML-parser, which is the one you get by default. As you can see it adds one closing `</br>` tag and converts one `<br>` to a `</br>`. In short, it doesn't do a very good job without closing tags. And that messes up what elements are supposed to be siblings.

`html5lib` on the other hand tries to match what a browser would do, and using it instead of `doc.replace("<br>", "<br/>")` would work as well. However, it is a lot slower, and it does not come with Python or BeautifulSoup so it requires another `pip install html5lib` to work.

Comment: Hey @Erik Vesteraas, not really understanding the purpose of the doc.replace. Could you elaborate please? thanks!